# wait_event_interruptible_timeout(wq, condition, timeout) polls cyclic the contition without being awakened

Tags: linux-device-driver

I have implemented the followig code in kernel 3.6.11 (emedded in ARM achitecture):

```
wait_queue_head_t i2c_waitQ;
init_waitqueue_head( &i2c_waitQ );
...
wait_event_interruptible_timeout( i2c_waitQ, !(fpga_register & 0x10000000), 
1000 )
```

Within ISR I have removed the related wake up function

```
//wake_up_interruptible( &i2c_waitQ );
```

Everywhere I read the following about this function:

**The condition is checked each time the waitqueue wq is woken up**

But I have not woken up the waitqueue and the condition (a FPGA register) will be polling cyclic.

What could be the cause ?